# Node.js express-admin "connect ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, user-interface, econnrefused

I'm trying to get a nice admin GUI for databasing for node.js like you get from phpmyadmin.

That's where I found express-admin.
http://simov.github.io/express-admin-site/

I follow their instructions and installed it with no problem. When I ran the app.js I entered in my credentials, "database type", "database name", etc. I choose the default port 3000 and after I was finished I received "connect ECONNREFUSED", nothing more. I tried different ports and even copy pasted the .json file they provided in the tutorial. nothing seemed to work.

I have no problem hosting my application I have been working on so I don't believe it's the port.. [and no I was not hosting my application as the same time]

Thank you guys I hope to get some feedback! (:

Answer (score 0):

Max, I'm the author of express-admin.

I just stumbled upon your question here. Even though a month have passed if you are still experiencing problems configuring the admin you can open up an issue here: https://github.com/simov/express-admin/issues (I get notified via email when someone opens up an issue there).

Also you should provide a more detailed information about your server/database set up + the full error message.

Comment: I have opened an issue detailing server, database and error received. In my case I'm using Heroku as server and a MySQL DB on port 3306. Receiving error "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306" after app initialization.